# How to change the colour xfce panel windowlist buttons flash

Tags: xubuntu, panel, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04.

I have a panel at the top of my screen, with a "Window Buttons" item on it that shows the list of open windows (panel-tasklist-menu).

I'm using a dark theme, and when the buttons "flash" to notify me they want attention, the colour is barely noticeable - I'd like it to flash to a more obvious/contrasting colour. I can change themes to get this effect, but I really like everything else about the theme I'm using.

I've tried looking for information about how to override the colour, but there doesn't seem to be a setting for it - other themes use other colours - so it must be possible. Does anyone know how I can change the colour it flashes to?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the exact same issue.

Found this solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1410349 
(How to change active window color in xfce panel?)

It demands you to be aware of the theme you are using and then alter the file called panel.rc.

It is located at (you should edit the file as root): /usr/share/themes/theme_name/gtk-2.0

Find the line with the instructions for the bg[ACTIVE] color. Change the hexadecimal code for the color and save the file.

Then, you should log out and than back in. The color should be as you set in the file...

Hope I helped you.

Comment: you can also restart the panel instead of logging out: `xfce4-panel -r`